# WHM / CPANEL new website is having an error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: cpanel, whm

So I created a new `Cpanel` using `WHM` I set the quota to `50MB` and the bandwidth to `50MB` as well. And I also uploaded the web files to `public_html` on `cpanel` successfully but when I load the website, an error that says `This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` appear.

**Here's the status screenshot.**

[image]

**And here's the screenshot of the files I uploaded.**

[image]

But still I get the error. Did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is connection timed out, definitely it is related to firewall. Do you have any firewall installed like CSF ? If so please try to check if your ISP IP (you can get ISP IP from http://whatismyip.com ) is blocked in the firewall.

Another possiblity is your server is having Selinux enabled. To disable that please try to

## setenforce 0

Another possiblity is server is having some default iptables rules

## iptables -L -n

If the above command is showing rules, then try to stop it

## service iptables stop

Let me know how it goes